# R Shiny app using ggvis gives error during upload

Tags: r, shiny, rcpp, dplyr, ggvis

I'm trying to host shiny apps that use the `ggvis` library on [shinyapps.io](http://shinyapps.io).
When uploading my app, the `runApp()` function fails when building the required packages to host the app. The error occurs when installing dplyr, which is used by ggvis. Dplyr in turn uses Rcpp, and the correct version is not retrieved from RCRAN, although it is available.

Can someone help me out here? Is there any way to specify package versions manually to circumvent this issue?

#### R code and steps needed to reproduce issue:

```
## ui.R
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  ggvisOutput("p"),
  uiOutput("p_ui")
))

## server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  input_width <- reactive(input$width)

  mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(~mpg) %>% 
    layer_histograms(width = input_width) %>%
    bind_shiny("ggvis", "ggvis_ui")
})


## When located in folder with ui.R and server.R file:
library("shiny")
library("shinyapps")
deployApp() # command that fails
```

Excerpt of the error:

```
...
[2014-10-28T16:05:00.464944786+0000] Building R package: dplyr (0.3.0.2)
/mnt/packages/build /mnt
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘dplyr’ ...
** package ‘dplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
Error: package ‘Rcpp’ 0.11.2 was found, but >= 0.11.3 is required by ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/dplyr’
################################### End Log ################################### 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 2477816 failed: Error building image: Error building dplyr (0.3.0.2). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
Execution halted
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252        LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message

> Error: package ‘Rcpp’ 0.11.2 was found, but >= 0.11.3 is required by ‘dplyr’

indicates that you are using an older version of R (maybe 3.0.2 ?) which searches in a tree containing only Rcpp 0.11.2.

The fix is simple: upgrade R.  Then install your dependencies, including the latest version of `Rcpp` with `install.packages("Rcpp")`.

Comment: I've added the sessionInfo of my R session in my question.
It appears I'm using the latest version of R already.
I believe the error occurs when the shinyapps package attempts to install dependencies to host the app online, so it shouldn't be related to my version of R.

Comment: Try running `install.packages("Rcpp")` to update your `Rcpp` package. That fixed the error for me.

Comment: Worked! I should've thought about this myself. Thanks for the fast reactions!

Comment: Hello, I encountered this same problem in my app, then updated Rcpp using install.packages(), and now see a different error message -- both with my app, and using the code posted by @filipsch above: at the end of the log (i.e. after installing packages and copying files) `Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 4638777 error: Unhandled Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` .. any ideas what might be going on here?